# Question on Function and Bijection

Tags: calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ and $g(x) = x+5$.
May I know is this function a bijection?

I know that it is a 1-to-1 function, but for onto, it doesn't get a integer $1$ as image. However the book stated that it is a bijection. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: See [Bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection): "a bijection or one-to-one correspondence is a function between the elements of two sets, where each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set. There are no unpaired elements.

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia concerning integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Answer (score 2):

It does get the integer $1$ in the image: $g(-4) = 1$. [You stated that the function is $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.]

Comment: but -4 isn't integer. its a negative integer.

Comment: @JaySun You literally said that it was an integer: specifically, a negative one. ("Integer" means "member of $\mathbb{Z} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, -1, -2, \dots\}$". "Natural" means "member of $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$", perhaps including $0$ as a natural number.)

Answer (score 1):

This function is indeed a bijection.
It is "obviously" surjective and injective. 
For $x=-4$, note that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ gives $g(-4)=-4+5=1$

You can also calculate that the inverse $g^{-1}:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is given by $x\mapsto x-5$.